# Why is there a release statement inside a viewDidUnload?

Tags: ios, memory-management

```
-(void)viewDidUnload{
    [childController release], childController = nil;
}

-(void)dealloc{
    [childController release];
}
```

I saw the above mentioned methods and was curious why childController is released in both?

Comment: Do not forget to send `[super dealloc]` at the end of your `-dealloc` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ViewDidUnload can be called during a low-memory warning situation when the view is not visible, in which case any objects that are created / retained in the loadView / viewDidLoad or retained NIB outlets need to be released.  These objects may / will be recreated if the view controller's view is referenced again / shown.  Obviously, not handling the releasing of objects in viewDidUnload can cause memory leaks and crashes.

Generally, you want to nil out the value in the viewDidUnload as well, so that a subsequent call to dealloc after a viewDidUnload (without the view being reloaded) doesn't cause a crash when calling release on a garbage object.

Generally, with properties, you just need to do a `self.childController = nil;` in the viewDidUnload, which handles both the release and nil'ing out of the object.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. I guess my understanding was that in viewDidUnload all we did was set stuff to nil and in dealloc we released stuff.